# How to process and find information from 2 files while keeping the first one open?

Tags: java, spring-batch

we have the following requirement:

We want to `read` and `process` 3 files in the following manner:

- We start by reading the first file, and when we process its first line:

  - We need to read (open) the second file, find and get some unique information that matches a (field) value from the (first) processed line of the first file.
  - If we find that information, we can enrich our model (`DTO`) with that value, and then skip the rest of the lines of the second file.
  - We need to read the third file, and do exactly the same thing we did for the second file, except that this time, we are looking for another information.
- Finally, we can proceed with the next line of the first file, and do the same thing we did for the first line.

In short, we need to always keep the first file opened, and for each line, we need to find a match in the other files, do some processing (transformation, enrichment, etc.) and if we finish iterating over all lines, we can then write our target model (object) into a new file.

Since we are already using `Spring Batch` as our ETL tool, is there something that it can offer for this need ? Thank you

Comment: You have to come up with your algorithm. No framework or library can provide the problem-solving technique for your very specific use-case.

Comment: +1 to what @GiorgiTsiklauri said. If you share an algorithm that solves your requirement, we can help you implement it with Spring Batch.

Comment: So this means that I need to implement a custom reader and to develop an algorithm inside it, right ? Still have doubts that this is going to work with a Spring batch step..